# How to use a table when a string is expected?

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

I'm attempting to run the following script to undertake deletion of items.
When I attempt to run it as is it provides me with the following error "7: Bad argument #1 to 'find' (stirng expected, got table)

I am very fresh to this and having a hard time working out how to allow for it to read the table.

I get it working when I put in UseContainerItemByName("Lost Sole") however I want it to delete all that come up in the table.

Thanks

```
    local DeleteCursor = function (...) return __LB__.Unlock(DeleteCursorItem, ...) end

function UseContainerItemByName(search)
   for bag = 0,4 do
      for slot = 1,GetContainerNumSlots(bag) do
         local item = GetContainerItemLink(bag,slot)
         if item and item:find(search) then
            PickupContainerItem(bag,slot)
            DeleteCursor(bag,slot)
         end
      end
   end
end

itemsToDelete = {
    "Lost Sole",
    "Oribobber",
    "Elysian Thade Bait",
    "Old Glove",
    "Rusty Chain",
    "Broken Fishing Pole",
    "Elysian Thade Bait",
    "Lost Sole Bait",
    "Partially Eaten Fish",
    "Shrouded Cloth Bandage"
}


UseContainerItemByName(itemsToDelete)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`item:find(search)` requires `search` to be a string pattern. Yet you passed a table (`itemsToDelete`) to `UseContainerItemByName`, and therefore into `search`.

Instead of `UseContainerItemByName(itemsToDelete)`, use

```lua
for _, item in ipairs (itemsToDelete) do
    UseContainerItemByName (item)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Alexander it did the job - i'll have to look into ipairs to see how this works further